# PDO num_rows count

Tags: php, base-de-datos, pdo

Tengo este select input que me da opción a elegir un nombre de todos los del despegable:

```
<td width="50%">
    <select class="form-control" id="acro_proyecto" name="acro_proyecto" required>

    <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : ''; ?> </option>
            <?php
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dmsgeneratorcode', 'root', '');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select acro_proyecto from proyectos');
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<option>' . $row['acro_proyecto'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Vale ahora una vez que ha sido elegido tiene que pintar automáticamente el número máximo de veces que está introducido en el siguiente input automáticamente:

```
<td width="50%">
    <input class="form-control numerodocumento" type="text" name="num_documento" id="num_documento" value="
        <?php
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dmsgeneratorcode', 'root', '');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select MAX(num_documento) from documento where proyecto='echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : '';);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<option>' . $row['num_documento'] . '</option>';
        }
        ?>" readonly />
</td>
```

Pero la línea donde recoge el valor me la pone en rojo como que la sintaxis está mal y eso es obvio. Sin embargo, no sé cómo ponerla bien para que recoga el dato del campo introducido anteriormente. Me da este error en el input en la aplicación web:

> ```
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ')'
> ```

Comment: Ignoro lo que pretendes hacer pero me parece que no es la mejor manera de hacerlo. Aunque ahora mismo el problema es que tienes un error de sintaxis : `$stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select MAX(num_documento) from documento where proyecto='echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : '';);` ¿por qué la línea termina con punto y coma, paréntesis, punto y coma? Esa línea está mal concatenada. También tus consultas SQL son vulnerables. Y... El título de la pregunta no tiene que ver con el error. ¿?

Comment: Sip, tenias razon, al final e realizado algo más facil, un combo box que lo que pido es que según el proyecto que selecciono en el segundo select me deja elegir el último numero de documento creado.

Comment: Es la primera vez que veo hacer una conexión a la base de datos dentro de un `select`. Generalmente conectas a la bd, extraes los datos en un arreglo y lees dicho arreglo para construir sea un `select`, sea una `table`, etc. Por otra parte, es poco performante consultar **dos veces a la base de datos**. En el `value` de cada `option` puedes almacenar varios datos, si son pequeños o si son numéricos. Ejemplo: `<select name="mySelect">
          <option value="1|Uno">Opción 1</option>
          <option value="2|Dos">Opción 2</option>
</select>` En el option tengo 2 valores separados por `|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select MAX(num_documento) from documento where 
proyecto='echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : '';);
```

en esta linea no estas concatenando bien revísala

Ademas, para sacar el maximo en sql tienes que agrupar la consulta utilizando [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)